# Accessing session in javascript ASP.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, session

I want to add data to the session from a JavaScript on asp.net web form. It did not work out properly..

this is my java script method, it just fetching the data from a text box it was working...

```
function JavaScriptFunction() {

            var arr = $("input[name='multiple[]']");

            $.each(arr, function (i, item) {
                //alert($(item).val());
                var userName = ($(item).val());
                '<%Session["UserName"] = "' + userName + '"; %>';
                  alert('<%=Session["UserName"] %>');
            });

            PageMethods.setemail("Paul Hayman");
            PageMethods.InsertContacts($(item).val(), "8989",
                    "M0011", OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
        }
```

but the problem was alert box just showing this

```
' + userName + '
```

when i add modify the code like this it's throwing an error  userName dose not exist in the current context....

```
 var userName = ($(item).val());
'<%Session["UserName"] = userName; %>';
 alert('<%=Session["UserName"] %>');
```

I just want to add text box value to the session.
Is there any other way to do it or how can i change this code snippet to work out as i wanted?

Comment: Take a look at this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattgi/archive/2006/11/15/accessing-session-data-from-javascript.aspx). It is old but still might fight your needs.

Comment: Oh boy. You cannot. Not like this. C# code between "<%" and "%>" is executed during html rendering server-side. Javascript is executed after the page html has arrived to the browser.

Comment: You are already using pagemethod send collection of username as parameter to your pagemethod.

Answer (score 0):

Asp is server side. Javascript isn't. You can't.

However there are lots of tricks to make it work.

I am not sure if you want to go from javascript to session or the other way round, as Igor made me notice in comments. Gonna explain you both:

**ASP to Javascript:**

```
Response.Write("<p id="&chr(34)&"user"&chr(34)&" style="&chr(34)&"visibility:hidden;value: "&chr(34)&Session(Username)&chr(34)&";"&chr(34)&">)
```

This will write as html this ASP code as a hidden field. Then, from javascript, you can get the value of it by:

```
var userName = document.getElementById("user").value;
```

**Javascript to ASP:**

As ASP runs in server-side, I decided to reload the same (or a different one) webpage sending javascript parameters at its location as follows:

javascript code to change location adding parameters:

```
 location.replace("randomPage.asp?userName=" + userName);
```

asp code to read those parameters:

```
<%
Session("username") = request.querystring("userName")
%>
```

Hope everythings clear. It might be other ways to do it, I don't know, that's the best I could find.

Comment: OP wants to push a value from javascript to Session, not the other way

Comment: Thank you Ssr1368 i wll try on this way

Comment: Hello @gamal how did it go? Could you vote this answer as useful if it was so or let me know if it wasn't? :)